# How to index an query country codes with lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm creating a lucene index for citynames and countrycodes (depending on each other). I want to countrycodes to be lowercase searchable and exact match.

At first, I now try to query a single countrycode and find all indexed elements that match that code. By my result is always empty.

```
//prepare
VERSION = Version.LUCENE_4_9;
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(VERSION, new SimpleAnalyzer());

//index
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StringField("countryCode", countryCode, Field.Store.YES));
writer.addDocument(doc);

//lookup
Query query = new QueryParser(VERSION, "countryCode", new SimpleAnalyzer()).parse(countryCode);
```

Result:
when I query for coutrycodes like "IT", "DE", "EN" etc, the result is always empty. Why?
Is `SimpleAnalyzer` from for 2-letter countrycodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused here.  I'll assume the your index writer is initialized in some part of your code not provided, but shy aren't you passing in `Version` into `SimpleAnalyzer`?  There is no no arg  constructor for `SimpleAnalyzer`, not since 3.X, anyway.

That's the only real issue I see.  Here is a working example using your code:

```
private static Version VERSION;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    //prepare
    VERSION = Version.LUCENE_4_9;
    Directory dir = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(VERSION, new SimpleAnalyzer(VERSION));
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);

    String countryCode = "DE";

    //index
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("countryCode", countryCode, Field.Store.YES));
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.close();

    IndexSearcher search = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(dir));
    //lookup
    Query query = new QueryParser(VERSION, "countryCode", new SimpleAnalyzer(VERSION)).parse(countryCode);

    TopDocs docs = search.search(query, 1);
    System.out.println(docs.totalHits);
}
```

Comment: I found the problem: I was using `StringField` instead of `TextField`, because the docs say: "A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is indexed as a single token.  For example this might be used for a 'country' field or an 'id'". Do you know why this is not working? It works when using `TextField` as you suggested.+

Comment: Yes,  that edit does explain it.   StringField doesn't get analyzed, the indexed representation is still upper case. You're query is still being analyzed though, so it will be lowercased by the SimpleAnalyzer.

Answer (score 2):

For *StringField*, you can use **TermQuery** instead of *QueryParser*

```
Directory dir = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_9, new SimpleAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9));
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);

String countryCode = "DE";

// index
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StringField("countryCode", countryCode, Store.YES));
writer.addDocument(doc);
writer.close();

IndexSearcher search = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(dir));
//lookup
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("countryCode", countryCode));

TopDocs docs = search.search(query, 1);
System.out.println(docs.totalHits);
```